# Flutter initializaiton in VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I've been working on a flutter project using VS Code. And when I opened my project today, there is a notification stating "Initializing flutter. This may take a few minutes", and it's struck there.

[image: Image showing the message]

Also, all the commands such as "flutter run" and "flutter doctor" are perfectly running and I am able to run my app through the terminal. But the other options such as Run Without Debugging are not working, and also the code auto-complete is showing no suggestions.
Can anyone please help me in solving the issue.

Comment: Do u have a launch.json?, if yes try to delete and recreate it again

Comment: Where is this file? I'm stuck with this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

First you should delete Flutter´s folder and then you must git clone -b master https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git. After you did it, Go to project or locate to your project in the terminal and enter first flutter channel, second flutter channel stable, last step flutter upgrade. (This is working for me on windows)

This page  https://medium.com/@psyanite/get-started-with-flutter-on-windows-3d3fbb8b221a can help you with some steps if you need install something else.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings.json file check that "dart.flutterSdkPath" has the correct location of the Flutter SDK to use. Or leave it blank to look for it in the project directory, FLUTTER_ROOT environment variable, and PATH environment variable