# Initializing Flutter. This may take a few minutes

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

first post (sorry for noobish post). I've searched Google and all over StackOverFlow to solve the above query on VSCode but to no avail anybody that can help solve this error I'd be really grateful!

It just keeps loading with the following message: Initializing Flutter. This may take a few minutes.

[Issue of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GLTm.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64181752/flutter-initializaiton-in-vscode

Comment: What *above query*? There is none above the first sentence. No query in the post title, either.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a issue with the Flutter installation, please make sure to delete your Flutter folder (the one you downloaded from the GitHub repo) and follow
[these instructions](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install) for your platform, step by step.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you was upgrading your `flutter` but due to some reason its not completely upgraded. I think you should try again to `upgrade` your flutter

Answer (score 1):

It is due to flutter upgrade. flutter upgrade is for upgrading your existing version of flutter.
So, Don't worry. This will take 5-10 minutes to upgrade. After you will be getting the updated flutter upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter` in the terminal. If there are any flutter or dart upgrades pending, this will check them and finish those. Then run a `flutter doctor`, just to make sure everything is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the the following lines in the CMD:

> `flutter channel dev`
>
> `flutter upgrade`

and it kept downloading till the message
Running pub upgrade...
then Close the CMD and for the message
"Initializing Flutter. This may take a few minutes"
Upgrading will actually take place in the Ide till it finishes
that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

I thinks replace folder flutter with download new flutter version can cut off time initializing flutter.

I tired waiting initializing by "flutter upgrade"